# How to stop search engines from indexing the hash links on WP page properly

Tags: wordpress, https, seo, search-engine, google-crawlers

I noticed all of the hash-links from the table of content on my blog have been indexed on google and I don't want that..
I don't want links like this to be indexed on google:
example.com/blog/post/#Header1
Because it's the same page as example.com/blog/post

How can I achieve that?

I tried googling the answer, it seemed like a common problem, but no help..